# Finding n0, asymptotic analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am attempting a textbook question about asymptotic analysis. The question goes:

**
The number of operations executed by algorithms A and B is 8nlogn and
2n^2, respectively. Determine n0 such that A is better than B for n ≥ n0.
**

So far my approach has been to draw a log-log graph with both lines and find the meeting point, I am thinking that this meeting point is at log(n0) so I can find n0 from it, the one that they are looking for, but things get strange here because the two lines never meet!

Here is the picture of my graph. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eUFkawKXCWiRBV6BV34Acs5SK4mBHMN4/view?usp=sharing

Any help with this problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: The picture is missing.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have added a link now. Here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eUFkawKXCWiRBV6BV34Acs5SK4mBHMN4/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

In principle it could be that $2n^2 = 8n\log n$ could have several solutions. However, this doesn't matter much: the derivative of $n/\log n$ is
$$
\frac{\log n - 1}{\log^2 n},
$$
and so if $2N^2 \geq 8N\log N$ for some $N \geq e$, it follows that $2n^2 \geq 8n\log n$ for all $n \geq N$.

Plugging in small values of $N$, we see that $2N^2 > 8N\log N$ for $N = 9$.

---

Here is an alternative proof. We first prove that if $n = e^k$ and $k \geq 4$ is an integer, then $2n^2 \geq 8en(\log n + 1)$. You can calculate that it holds for the base case $k = 4$. Assuming that it holds for some $k \geq 4$, we prove it for $k + 1$. The induction hypothesis implies that
$$
2e^{2(k+1)} = e^2 \cdot 2e^{2k} \geq e^2 \cdot 8ee^k (k+1) = 8ee^{k+1} (k+2) \cdot e \cdot \frac{k+1}{k+2}.
$$
To complete the proof, it suffices to check that $e (k+1)/(k+2) \geq 1$, or equivalently, that $e \geq (k+2)/(k+1) = 1 + 1/(k+1)$, which trivially holds since $k \geq 4$.

Now let $n \geq e^4$ be arbitrary, and let $k = \lfloor \log n \rfloor$. Then
$$
2n^2 \geq 2(e^k)^2 \geq 2ee^k(k+1) > 2n\log n.
$$

Comment: Eh. Ok I think you're moving too fast. First of all, where did the derivative come from. In the textbook there was no talk of calculus so I don't know how you used it to solve the problem.

Comment: In mathematics we are allowed to use whatever tools we wish. We can use calculus if we wish. We can use linear algebra if we wish. We can use complex analysis if we wish. The only rule is that the argument should be logically valid.

Comment: In this problem, we can use induction to prove that $n \geq \log n$ for large enough $n$, but I see no reason to tie my hands behind my back just because your textbook doesn't mention calculus. Calculus is part of the common toolkit of all mathematicians.

Comment: I hear you but that would be killing a mosquito using RPG. I have never understood calculus so when I see derivative I skip a beat

Comment: This is a good reason to become friends with calculus, which is the basis of all modern science. As you can see, the inductive proof is much less clean.

Comment: OK I really like the alternative solution but still, I don't think its what the textbook wants. This is about asymptotic analysis. Big 0

Comment: I am thinking that if I multiply one of the equations by a constant c, such that we have y' = cy we may get the lines to cross and thus find n0

Comment: In other words, we are trying to show that 2n^2 is big O of 8nlogn for some c and n0. So what's that n0? That's the question. I think

Comment: Even if you determine a point at which $2n_0^2 = 8n_0\log n_0$ (which you can find numerically), this doesn't automatically guarantee that $2n^2 \geq 8n\log n$ for all $n \geq n_0$. You have to prove it somehow.

Comment: Hah! I got it. From my graph it appears that that point is 0

Comment: That's the idea of asymptotes right. It never reaches but always gets closer. log(0) is undefined. So that means x=0 is an asymptote for fn1. Which means for all n>0, 2n^2 is greater than 8nlogn

Comment: I'm afraid that's false for $n=2,\ldots,8$ (assuming that by $\log$ you mean natural logarithm). You can check it yourself. This shows that your heuristic fails.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the type of log matters. I went into the textbook and found that log(n) is always in base 2. Drawing the new graph showed that the point is somewhere around 16 but I am not sure. However I found out that I can calculate it from 8nlogn = 2n^2. I am stuck here: 4logn = n. How do I proceed. Induction doesnt give me n, it just proves logn < n^2. Maybe calculus could help, should I start learning calculus? Will it solve the problem?

Comment: You don't have to solve the equation $n=4\log n$. You just have to find $n_0$ such that $n \geq 4\log n$ for all $n \geq n_0$. For example, $n_0=1000$ would work.

Comment: To prove that $n \geq 4\log n$ for all $n \geq n_0$, you can use either of the two methods in my answer.

Comment: Ahh! I get you. Since there are many n0's, we just have to pick any that works and prove that the all n >= n0 work.  Alright. I will go with the first method. I know how to differentiate and integrate, on paper. But why did you pick the derivate of n / log n ? Why that expression? Also, why is the derivative useful to us, what does it tell us?

Comment: We want to show that the ratio between $2n^2$ and $8n\log n$ is increasing from some point on. We can prove that using elementary calculus.

Comment: Okk. So you dropped the 4 since you dont need it during differentiation, since its a constant. Differiated and got that expression. Now we just need to prove that there exists n such that that that expression is greater that 0. So we have: logn - 1 > 0. We get n > 2. Right?

Comment: So can we say that from n = 2 the difference keeps increasing?

Comment: You’ll have to take it from here.

Comment: Thats OK. Thanks alot!!!!!!!